# How to put a script and object in a HAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, haml, rollbar

I am trying to add rollbar to a Rails application that uses React for the front-end. I need to place a script in my HAML file that will allow for rollbar configuration, however the script, and subsequent objects are not playing nice with the HAML file.

This is what I need to put in the HAML file

```
<script>
var _rollbarConfig = {
    accessToken: "POST_CLIENT_ITEM_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    captureUncaught: true,
    captureUnhandledRejections: true,
    payload: {
        environment: "production"
    }
};
// Rollbar Snippet
!function(r){var e={};function o(n){if(e[n])return e[n].exports;var t=e[n]={i:n,l:!1,exports:{}};return r[n].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,o),t.l=!0,t.exports}o.m=r,o.c=e,o.d=function(r,e,n){o.o(r,e)||Object.defineProperty(r,e,{enumerable:!0,get:n})},o.r=function(r){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(r,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(r,"__esModule",{value:!0})},o.t=function(r,e){if(1&e&&(r=o(r)),8&e)return r;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof r&&r&&r.__esModule)return r;var n=Object.create(null);if(o.r(n),Object.defineProperty(n,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:r}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof r)for(var t in r)o.d(n,t,function(e){return r[e]}.bind(null,t));return n},o.n=function(r){var e=r&&r.__esModule?function(){return r.default}:function(){return r};return o.d(e,"a",e),e},o.o=function(r,e){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(r,e)},o.p="",o(o.s=0)}([function(r,e,o){var n=o(1),t=o(4);_rollbarConfig=_rollbarConfig||{},_rollbarConfig.rollbarJsUrl=_rollbarConfig.rollbarJsUrl||"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rollbar.js/2.8.1/rollbar.min.js",_rollbarConfig.async=void 0===_rollbarConfig.async||_rollbarConfig.async;var a=n.setupShim(window,_rollbarConfig),l=t(_rollbarConfig);window.rollbar=n.Rollbar,a.loadFull(window,document,!_rollbarConfig.async,_rollbarConfig,l)},function(r,e,o){var n=o(2);function t(r){return function(){try{return r.apply(this,arguments)}catch(r){try{console.error("[Rollbar]: Internal error",r)}catch(r){}}}}var a=0;function l(r,e){this.options=r,this._rollbarOldOnError=null;var o=a++;this.shimId=function(){return o},"undefined"!=typeof window&&window._rollbarShims&&(window._rollbarShims[o]={handler:e,messages:[]})}var i=o(3),d=function(r,e){return new l(r,e)},s=function(r){return new i(d,r)};function c(r){return t(function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0),o={shim:this,method:r,args:e,ts:new Date};window._rollbarShims[this.shimId()].messages.push(o)})}l.prototype.loadFull=function(r,e,o,n,a){var l=!1,i=e.createElement("script"),d=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],s=d.parentNode;i.crossOrigin="",i.src=n.rollbarJsUrl,o||(i.async=!0),i.onload=i.onreadystatechange=t(function(){if(!(l||this.readyState&&"loaded"!==this.readyState&&"complete"!==this.readyState)){i.onload=i.onreadystatechange=null;try{s.removeChild(i)}catch(r){}l=!0,function(){var e;if(void 0===r._rollbarDidLoad){e=new Error("rollbar.js did not load");for(var o,n,t,l,i=0;o=r._rollbarShims[i++];)for(o=o.messages||[];n=o.shift();)for(t=n.args||[],i=0;i<t.length;++i)if("function"==typeof(l=t[i])){l(e);break}}"function"==typeof a&&a(e)}()}}),s.insertBefore(i,d)},l.prototype.wrap=function(r,e,o){try{var n;if(n="function"==typeof e?e:function(){return e||{}},"function"!=typeof r)return r;if(r._isWrap)return r;if(!r._rollbar_wrapped&&(r._rollbar_wrapped=function(){o&&"function"==typeof o&&o.apply(this,arguments);try{return r.apply(this,arguments)}catch(o){var e=o;throw e&&("string"==typeof e&&(e=new String(e)),e._rollbarContext=n()||{},e._rollbarContext._wrappedSource=r.toString(),window._rollbarWrappedError=e),e}},r._rollbar_wrapped._isWrap=!0,r.hasOwnProperty))for(var t in r)r.hasOwnProperty(t)&&(r._rollbar_wrapped[t]=r[t]);return r._rollbar_wrapped}catch(e){return r}};for(var p="log,debug,info,warn,warning,error,critical,global,configure,handleUncaughtException,handleAnonymousErrors,handleUnhandledRejection,captureEvent,captureDomContentLoaded,captureLoad".split(","),u=0;u<p.length;++u)l.prototype[p[u]]=c(p[u]);r.exports={setupShim:function(r,e){if(r){var o=e.globalAlias||"Rollbar";if("object"==typeof r[o])return r[o];r._rollbarShims={},r._rollbarWrappedError=null;var a=new s(e);return t(function(){e.captureUncaught&&(a._rollbarOldOnError=r.onerror,n.captureUncaughtExceptions(r,a,!0),n.wrapGlobals(r,a,!0)),e.captureUnhandledRejections&&n.captureUnhandledRejections(r,a,!0);var t=e.autoInstrument;return!1!==e.enabled&&(void 0===t||!0===t||"object"==typeof t&&t.network)&&r.addEventListener&&(r.addEventListener("load",a.captureLoad.bind(a)),r.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",a.captureDomContentLoaded.bind(a))),r[o]=a,a})()}},Rollbar:s}},function(r,e){function o(r,e,o){if(e.hasOwnProperty&&e.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener")){for(var n=e.addEventListener;n._rollbarOldAdd&&n.belongsToShim;)n=n._rollbarOldAdd;var t=function(e,o,t){n.call(this,e,r.wrap(o),t)};t._rollbarOldAdd=n,t.belongsToShim=o,e.addEventListener=t;for(var a=e.removeEventListener;a._rollbarOldRemove&&a.belongsToShim;)a=a._rollbarOldRemove;var l=function(r,e,o){a.call(this,r,e&&e._rollbar_wrapped||e,o)};l._rollbarOldRemove=a,l.belongsToShim=o,e.removeEventListener=l}}r.exports={captureUncaughtExceptions:function(r,e,o){if(r){var n;if("function"==typeof e._rollbarOldOnError)n=e._rollbarOldOnError;else if(r.onerror){for(n=r.onerror;n._rollbarOldOnError;)n=n._rollbarOldOnError;e._rollbarOldOnError=n}e.handleAnonymousErrors();var t=function(){var o=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0);!function(r,e,o,n){r._rollbarWrappedError&&(n[4]||(n[4]=r._rollbarWrappedError),n[5]||(n[5]=r._rollbarWrappedError._rollbarContext),r._rollbarWrappedError=null),e.handleUncaughtException.apply(e,n),o&&o.apply(r,n)}(r,e,n,o)};o&&(t._rollbarOldOnError=n),r.onerror=t}},captureUnhandledRejections:function(r,e,o){if(r){"function"==typeof r._rollbarURH&&r._rollbarURH.belongsToShim&&r.removeEventListener("unhandledrejection",r._rollbarURH);var n=function(r){var o,n,t;try{o=r.reason}catch(r){o=void 0}try{n=r.promise}catch(r){n="[unhandledrejection] error getting `promise` from event"}try{t=r.detail,!o&&t&&(o=t.reason,n=t.promise)}catch(r){}o||(o="[unhandledrejection] error getting `reason` from event"),e&&e.handleUnhandledRejection&&e.handleUnhandledRejection(o,n)};n.belongsToShim=o,r._rollbarURH=n,r.addEventListener("unhandledrejection",n)}},wrapGlobals:function(r,e,n){if(r){var t,a,l="EventTarget,Window,Node,ApplicationCache,AudioTrackList,ChannelMergerNode,CryptoOperation,EventSource,FileReader,HTMLUnknownElement,IDBDatabase,IDBRequest,IDBTransaction,KeyOperation,MediaController,MessagePort,ModalWindow,Notification,SVGElementInstance,Screen,TextTrack,TextTrackCue,TextTrackList,WebSocket,WebSocketWorker,Worker,XMLHttpRequest,XMLHttpRequestEventTarget,XMLHttpRequestUpload".split(",");for(t=0;t<l.length;++t)r[a=l[t]]&&r[a].prototype&&o(e,r[a].prototype,n)}}}},function(r,e){function o(r,e){this.impl=r(e,this),this.options=e,function(r){for(var e=function(r){return function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0);if(this.impl[r])return this.impl[r].apply(this.impl,e)}},o="log,debug,info,warn,warning,error,critical,global,configure,handleUncaughtException,handleAnonymousErrors,handleUnhandledRejection,_createItem,wrap,loadFull,shimId,captureEvent,captureDomContentLoaded,captureLoad".split(","),n=0;n<o.length;n++)r[o[n]]=e(o[n])}(o.prototype)}o.prototype._swapAndProcessMessages=function(r,e){var o,n,t;for(this.impl=r(this.options);o=e.shift();)n=o.method,t=o.args,this[n]&&"function"==typeof this[n]&&("captureDomContentLoaded"===n||"captureLoad"===n?this[n].apply(this,[t[0],o.ts]):this[n].apply(this,t));return this},r.exports=o},function(r,e){r.exports=function(r){return function(e){if(!e&&!window._rollbarInitialized){for(var o,n,t=(r=r||{}).globalAlias||"Rollbar",a=window.rollbar,l=function(r){return new a(r)},i=0;o=window._rollbarShims[i++];)n||(n=o.handler),o.handler._swapAndProcessMessages(l,o.messages);window[t]=n,window._rollbarInitialized=!0}}}}]);
// End Rollbar Snippet
</script>
```

Comment: "Not playing nice" is colorful, but not very helpful. Are you getting errors? If so, what. If not, what information do you have that might inform an answer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". You're not telling us enough to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my layout add:

```
  = yield(:javascript)
```

and in view

```
 - content_for :javascript do
  :javascript
    $(function(){
      //your indented multiline javascript code
    })
```